# Why is .getAttribute returning null for data-* attribute

Tags: javascript, dom

I have some HTML and I'm trying to get the value of "data-nChargers" with this script

```js
var noOfChargers = document.getElementById("chargers-list")
                   .getAttribute("nChargers");
console.log(noOfChargers);
```

```html
<div id="chargers-list" data-nChargers="4"></div>
```

but it returns null. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The attribute is not nChargers, it's `data-nChargers`

Comment: you can't have the word `is` twice in that title

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The attribute is `data-nChargers` which can be accessed through `dataset` or `getAttribute("data-nChargers")`

```js
var e = document.getElementById("chargers-list");

console.log(e.getAttribute("data-nChargers"));

console.log(e.dataset.nchargers);
```

```html
<div id="chargers-list" data-nChargers="4"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

`getAttribute("data-nChargers");` instead.

This happens because getAttribute method looks for that exact name. If you want to get data attributes you should use `.dataset.nChargers` instead.

More information in :
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes

Best regards.

Comment: Can you please explain why, for future visitors?

Comment: I did try that too.  Still got null.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `getAttribute("nChargers");` to `getAttribute("data-nChargers");`

```js
var noOfChargers = document.getElementById("chargers-list"). getAttribute("data-nchargers")
console.log(noOfChargers);
```

```html
<div id="chargers-list" data-nChargers="4"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The full attribute name is `data-nChargers`, not simply `nChargers`.

`document.getElementById("chargers-list").getAttribute('data-nChargers')`

If you want to use only `nChargers`, you could use the `dataset` property:

`document.getElementById("chargers-list").dataset.nChargers`

`dataset` ignores the `data-` prefix and converts dashed words (ie `n-chargers`) to camel-case (ie `nChargers`).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset

Answer (score 0):

The modern way is using `dataset`. Note the attribute name is lowercased and then hyphens are removed and converted to camel case.

```js
console.log(document.getElementById("chargers-list").dataset.nchargers);
```

```html
<div id="chargers-list" data-nChargers="4"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `getAttribute()` function requires you to use the whole name of the attribute. In this case `data-nchargers`.

Another option is to use the `dataset` property.  In this case it would not require the `data-` prefix.

```
var list = document.getElementById("chargers-list");
var noOfChargers = list.dataset.nchargers;
console.log(noOfChargers);
```